# Prove that $C[a,b]$ with inner product $\langle f,g\rangle:=\int_a^bf(t)\overline{g(t)}dt$ is not a Hilbert space.

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis

Prove that $C[a,b]$ with inner product $<f,g>:=\int_a^bf(t)\overline{g(t)}dt$ is not a Hilbert space.

Now the norm induced by the inner product is

\begin{align}
||f||&=\sqrt{<f,f>}\\
&=\sqrt{\int_a^bf(t)\overline{f(t)}dt}\\
&=\sqrt{\int_a^b|f(t)|^2dt}
\end{align}

This is a Hilbert space if it is a Banach space with $||x||$, so to show that this is not a Hilbert space I must show that this is not a Banach space.

To do this I must find a Cauchy sequence in $C[a,b]$ that does not converge. But I am confused as to how to to this in $C[a,b]$.

Any suggestions as to how to find such a sequence or hints are appreciated.

EDIT:

Could this series work:

$
f_n(t) = \begin{cases}
  0 & \text{for $x \in [a,a+\frac{b-a}{2}]$}\\
  n(x-a-\frac{b-a}{2}) & \text{for $x \in (a+\frac{b-a}{2},a+\frac{b-a}{2}+\frac{b-a}{3n}]$} \\
  1 & \text{for $x \in (a+\frac{b-a}{2}+\frac{b-a}{3n},b]$}
\end{cases}
$

Comment: see edit, I think this might work.

Comment: instead of a $\frac{1}{2}$ I could use $\frac{b-a}{2}$? for the linear part, would it still work if I said $nx$ instead of $n(x-a-\frac{1}{2})$?

Comment: So would $f_n(x)=\left(\frac{x-a}{b-a}\right)^n$ work?

Comment: I'm going to try $\frac{b-a}{3n}$

Comment: Your idea is right, but you still have a scaling issue with the second part of the piecewise definition for $f_n$. The width of the second interval is now $\frac{b-a}{3n}$, and the function needs to increase by $1$ in that interval. So the slope needs to be $\frac{3n}{b-a}$, whereas it is currently $n$.

Comment: Another way you can show that it's not a Hilbert space is by showing that the parallelogram law doesn't hold.

Comment: @Poppy: This space is an inner product space, so the parallelogram law does hold. The reason it fails to be a Hilbert space is that it's not complete.

Comment: @Bungo, you are completely right. I overlooked (though I don't know how :)) it's not $C[a,b]$ with the sup norm.