# Is this inner product space also a Hilbert space?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, hilbert-spaces, complete-spaces

Let $X$ be the set of all the real- (or complex-) valued functions that are defined and continuous on a closed interval $[a, b]$ on the real line, where $a$ and $b$ are some fixed real numbers such that $a < b$, with the inner product defined by
$$
\langle x, y \rangle := \int_a^b  x(t) \overline{y(t)}  dt. \tag{0} 
$$

Is this inner product space also a Hilbert space?

My Attempt:

> Let $\left( x_n \right)_{n \in \mathbb{N} }$ be a Cauchy sequence in $X$. Then, given any real number $\varepsilon > 0$, there exists a natural number $N_\varepsilon$ such that
> $$ 
> \left\lVert x_m, x_n \right\rVert = \sqrt{ \int_a^b \left\lvert x_m(t)  - x_n(t) \right\rvert^2} < \varepsilon  \tag{1}
> $$
> for any natural numbers $m$ and $n$ such that $m > N_\varepsilon$ and $n > N_\varepsilon$. [Refer to (0) above.]

What next? How to proceed from here? Or, is there a Cauchy sequence that fails to converge in our inner product space $X$?

PS:

Based on the Hint given by
@belkacemabderrahmane, here is what I do further:

> For each $n \in \mathbb{N}$, let us define the function $x_n \colon [a, b] \longrightarrow \mathbb{C}$ by the formula
> $$
> x_n(t) := \left( \frac{t-a}{b-a} \right)^n. \tag{2} 
> $$
> Then we find that, for any natural numbers $m$ and $n$, we have
> $$
> \begin{align}
> & \ \ \ \left\lVert x_m - x_n \right\rVert \\
> &= \sqrt{ \int_a^b \left\lvert \left( \frac{t-a}{b-a} \right)^m - \left( \frac{t-a}{b-a} \right)^n \right\rvert^2 dt } \\
> &= \sqrt{ \int_a^b \left[ \left( \frac{t-a}{b-a} \right)^m - \left( \frac{t-a}{b-a} \right)^n \right]^2 dt } \\
> &= \sqrt{ \int_a^b \left[ \left( \frac{t-a}{b-a} \right)^{2m} - 2 \left( \frac{t-a}{b-a} \right)^{m+n} + \left( \frac{t-a}{b-a} \right)^{2n} \right] dt } \\
> &= \sqrt{ \frac{1}{(b-a)^{2m}} \int_a^b (t-a)^{2m} dt - \frac{2}{(b-a)^{m+n} } \int_a^b (t-a)^{m+n} dt + \frac{1}{(b-a)^{2n} } \int_a^b (t-a)^{2n} dt } \\
> &= \sqrt{ \frac{1}{(b-a)^{2m}} \frac{(b-a)^{2m+1} }{ 2m+1} - \frac{2}{(b-a)^{m+n} } \frac{ (b-a)^{ m+n+1 } }{ m+n+1 } + \frac{1}{(b-a)^{2n} }  \frac{ (b-a)^{2n+1} }{ 2n+1}  } \\
> &= \sqrt{ (b-a) \left[ \frac{1}{2m+1} - \frac{2}{m+n+1} + \frac{1}{2n+1} \right] }, 
> \end{align}
> $$
> which can be made as small as we please by taking $m$ and $n$ sufficiently large. Thus our sequence $\left( x_n \right)_{n \in \mathbb{N} }$ is indeed a Cauchy sequence.

> Suppose that this sequnece converges to some point $x \in X$. Then we have
> $$
> \lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt{ \int_a^b \left\lvert x_n(t) - x(t) \right\rvert^2 } = 0, 
> $$
> which implies
> $$
> \lim_{n \to \infty} \int_a^b \left\lvert x_n(t) - x(t) \right\rvert^2  = 0
> $$
> also.

How to proceed from here? How to show rigorously and in detail that this function $x$ is not in our space?

Comment: For a Cauchy sequence that fails to converge see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3646131/show-the-space-of-continuous-functions-on-0-1-with-the-2-norm-for-functions

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/934368/42969

Comment: Continuity is an obstacle, as the polynomials are dense in $L^2(a,b)$ but not every function in $L^2(a,b)$ is continuous.

Comment: Check the function for $t=b$ and $t<b$.

Comment: The problem with the proposed hint is that the sequence $\{x_n\}$ in the hint **does** converge to an element of $X$, namely it converges to zero! (This is even implicit in the calculation you did—just look at the term involving $x_m$, say.)

Answer (score 1):

Let's take $[a,b] = [0,1]$ for simplicity. A better try would be to take the functions which are
$$
x_n(t) = \begin{cases} 0 & t < 1/2 - 1/n\\
\text{linear} & 1/2-1/n \le t < 1/2 \\
1 & 1/2 \le t.
\end{cases}
$$
This was a hint provided in another question that was linked in the comments. Suppose that $x$ is a continuous function such that $x_n\to x$ in $X$. Then for any $\epsilon > 0$, check for yourself
$$
\int_0^{1/2-\epsilon}|x(t)|^2\,dt = 0,
$$
and
$$
\int_{1/2}^1|x(t)-1|^2\,dt = 0.
$$
Since we assume $x$ is continuous (i.e., $x\in X$), by standard arguments, you can conclude that $x(t) = 1$ for $t\ge 1/2$, and $x(t) = 0$ for $t < 1/2$. Why is this a contradiction?